# Can not figure out how to detect how many consecutive Heads in a Coin Flipper

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I have a project I am working on in my java class and cannot figure out what a few lines of code.

The project consists of flipping a coin and using various methods to detect how many heads or tails as well as how many flips have occurred so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GVcoin{

// true for heads, false for tails
private boolean isHeads;
private int flips, heads;
private Random r;


//Create the coin 
public GVcoin(){
    r = new Random();
    heads = 0;
    flips = 0;
    isHeads = true;     
}

//Flip the coin by random choosing true / false
public void flip(){
    isHeads = r.nextBoolean();
    flips++;
    if(isHeads){
        heads++;
    }
}

//return true if coin is currently heads
public boolean isHeads(){
    return isHeads;
}    

//return String representation of important values
public String toString(){
    String str;
    str = "Flips: " + flips + " Heads: " + heads + " isHeads: " + isHeads;
    return str;
}    

//return number of total flips
public int numFlips(){
    return flips;
}

//return number of total heads  
public int numHeads(){
    return heads;
}

//return number of total tails
public int numTails(){
    return flips - heads;
}

//Set the coin to heads (or tails) to start
public void setToHeads(boolean h){
    isHeads = h;
}

//Create the coin with a random seed
public GVcoin(int seed){
    this();
    r = new Random(seed);
}    

}
```

The problem I can not seem to figure out is in a different class called TossingCoins and is the method `public int consecutiveHeads(GVcoin c, int goal)`

```
public class TossingCoins {

public int countHeads(GVcoin c, int goal){
    while(c.numHeads() != goal) {
        c.flip(); 
    } 
    return c.numFlips();
}

public int flipForTails(GVcoin c, int goal){
    while(c.numTails() != goal) {
        c.flip(); 
    } 
    return c.numFlips();
}

public int consecutiveHeads(GVcoin c, int goal){
    while(c.numHeads() != goal){
        c.flip();
    }
}
// This method creates a TossingCoins object and calls the method for testing
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TossingCoins game = new TossingCoins();
    GVcoin c = new GVcoin();
    int numHeads = game.countHeads(c, 100);
}
}
```

What I have tried so far is see if the numHeads is not equal to the goal of heads. Then if it is not equal to the number of heads(goal), I would set the flip to add one. Which wold count 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on till it hits the amount flips needed to hit the number of heads(goal).

Comment: What is `consecutiveHeads` supposed to return?

Comment: It will return ow many flips it takes to record that many consecutive heads (goal). e.g. (5 goal) so it will take like 80 flips to get 5 heads in a row.

Comment: Well I just do not know how to structure the loop.

Comment: Does the code you have above not work?

Comment: It does not. I get an error saying consecutiveHeads(c, 5) incorrectly returns 8 instead of 50

Comment: The code that you have above will not compile; there is no return statement. What do you have in your actual code?

Comment: My bad, it returns return c.numFlips(); , but I know that is wrong. I just don't know how to get the method to detect how many flips are needed to reach the goal of heads.

Comment: Think about what is different between `flipForTails` and `consecutiveHeads`. (Hint: *consecutive* is the word that should jump out at you here)

Comment: So your saying take `flipForTails() - consecutiveHeads()`?

Comment: No I mean what are you doing in `flipForTails()`? (You are counting how many flips it takes to get the desired number of tails) Now what are you trying to do in`consecutiveHeads()`? (Again think about the word *consecutive* in the method name)

Comment: I am trying to count the consecutive number of times the coin flips towards heads.

Comment: And does `while(c.numHeads() != goal){
        c.flip();
    }` do that? What happens if you flip Heads, tails, Heads, Heads, Heads, Heads?

Comment: Well, when you execute the method it will look for how many times it hits the desired goal, not how many times consecutively it hits the desired code. So, if you flip Heads, tails, Heads, Heads, Heads, Heads and say the goal was 5 it would finish even though it didn't hit 5 in a row but instead it flipped to heads 5 times.

Comment: Exactly. So you need to keep a counter of consecutive heads, and loop while that is less than the target. Something like: `int consec = 0; while (consec < goal) { flip(); if(c.isHeads()) consec++; else consec = 0; }`

Comment: I never thought about using a counter... Thank You!